# Sql to LINQ Query how to apply sub query in LINQ

Tags: sql

```
**SELECT DISTINCT S.SUPPNAME, S.SUPPCODE  FROM ET_POHEAD P, EM_SUPP_MST S
 WHERE TRIM(ORDTYPCODE) IN 
(SELECT ORDTYPCODE FROM EM_ORDTYP_MST WHERE PYMT_VCHR = ''Y'')
 AND RTRIM(STATCODE) = ''000090'' AND p.suppid  = s.suppid     
ORDER BY 2;**
```

Please give me solution of this query..
Sorry guys i m new in LINQ query...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this really is exactly what stackoverflow is for, but I'll give you some rough guidelines:

```
From p in et_pohead, s in em_supp_mst
Where ( (from m in em_ordtyp_mst where m.pymt_vchr = "Y").contains(s.ordtypcode)
and s.statcode.rtrim() = "000090" and p.suppid = s.suppid )
Select s.suppname, s.suppcode Distinct
```

I'd really be surprised if that just works (typed from memory), but give it a shot. Hopefully you'll be able to work out the rest.